# Search bar not disappearing with div height animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that I used to just use JS to hide and show and this worked fine, however after using height to show and hide the div the search bar (inside the div) doesn't disappear even though it is contained within the div. **[I dont want to use jQuery]**
Before:
[image]
After:
[image]
JS:

```
document.getElementById('top_line_2a').addEventListener('click', function() {
      var searchClickIcon = document.getElementById('top_line_2a');
      var searchClick = document.getElementById('top_line_3');
      if(searchClick.style.height == '0em') {
        //searchClick.style.display = 'block';
        searchClick.style.height = '3em';
        searchClickIcon.style.color = 'white';
        searchClickIcon.style.textShadow = '0px 0px 7px white';
        document.getElementsByClassName('search')[0].focus();
      } else {
        //searchClick.style.display = 'none';
        searchClick.style.height = '0em';
        searchClickIcon.style.color = 'rgba(255, 187, 61, 1)';
        searchClickIcon.style.textShadow = '';
      }
    })
```

HTML:

```
<div id='top_line_3'><div class='search-main'><input class='search' placeholder="Search for a product" type='text'/></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#top_line_3 {
    clear: both;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
    box-shadow: inset 0 5px 5px #1c1c1c;
}
```

Comment: How is your search `<input>` element positioned? If it's positioned relative or absolute, your change to its container's height is going to do nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<div>` will still show it's contents if the height is zero. To counter this you can set the `overflow:hidden` CSS property on the `<div>`. Elements outside it's boundary will be hidden.

Also if a property's value is zero you don't need to specify a unit. `0em, 0px, ...` is the same as `0`.